# how to make multiple requests using request module node.js?

Tags: node.js, request, web-scraping

i am using `nodejs request module`. how to make multiple requests for a session after user login using this? how to make sure that the user is logged in and form data is successfuly submitted using request module?
i am trying the example in the docs to submit the form for user login but it always redirects on the default page.
can anyone guide me through?

THANKS

Answer (score 0):

You need to save cookie after login request, use cookie in next request.

```
var cookie = null
login()

function login() {
    request(host)
        .post('/rest/user/login')
        .send({email: 'email@domain.com', password: 'qweqwe'})
        .expect('Content-Type', /json/)
        .expect(200)
        .end(function (err, res) {
            if (err) throw err
            if (!res.body.error) {
                cookie = res.headers['set-cookie']
                nextRequest()
            }
        })
}
function nextRequest() {
    request(host)
        .post('/rest/data')
        .set('cookie', cookie)
        .send({
            data: 'data'
        })
        .expect('Content-Type', /json/)
        .expect(200)
        .end(function (err, res) {
            if (err) throw err
            console.log(res.body.data)
    })
}
```

Comment: THANKS a lot for quick response....it was giving me "host is undefined". i provide it is haost="example.com"... now its giving "Object #<Request> has no method post"... can u guide me further? thanks

Comment: oh, sorry. This code used [supertest](https://www.npmjs.org/package/supertest). You can use this module . if you want i will post the [request](https://www.npmjs.org/package/request) example.

Comment: plz provide the example of request.. it will be a grate favor... thanks

Answer (score 0):

As your wish request example, this tested. [Here are](https://www.npmjs.org/package/request) simple use.

```
var request = require('request');
var host = 'http://localhost'
var loginUrl = host + '/rest/user/login'
var nextUrl = host + '/rest/next/request'

var j = request.jar()


function login(jar, callback) {
    request.post({url: loginUrl, jar: jar}, callback).form({username: 'user1', password: 'pass1'})
}

function post(jar, callback) {
    request.post({url: nextUrl, jar: jar}, callback).form({id: 1})
}
login(j, function (err, response, body) {
    //check err, response, body
    post(j, function(err, response, body){
        //check err, response, body
        console.log(body)
    })
})
```

Comment: thanks a lot for the example.... the site i am trying to access does not have the REST architecture....its login page url looks like "https://example.com/default.aspx"... when i tried the code its first response is with status 200 and body contain the default page... but the 2nd one is with status 302 & location is  "default.aspx"....can u guide me where is the problem... the user is not authenticated?  or any other issue? i have also used "strictSSl: false" because it gives ssl certificate erorr...